# Should I use resource routing even for non-CRUD routes (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Is it considered best practice to use [resourceful routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) in Rails whenever possible, even if the CRUD verbs don't really match the actions being performed (details follow)?

In my Rails app, I'm implementing an OAuth login system using [`sorcery`](https://github.com/Sorcery/sorcery)'s `external` module. I closely followed their official [tutorial](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/External), which defines the routes for the OAuth methods like this.

```rb
# config/routes.rb
post "oauth/callback" => "oauths#callback"
get "oauth/callback" => "oauths#callback" # for use with Github, Facebook
get "oauth/:provider" => "oauths#oauth", :as => :auth_at_provider
```

Basically, `auth_at_provider` is called when the user clicks the "Login via [Provider Name]" button, and the `callback` is called once they log in via the external provider.

I left the routes as-is, but a teammate reviewing it suggested we use resource routing, like this for example:

```rb
resources :oauth only: [:index, :create, :show]
```

I guess this is technically possible, but for me the singular routes defined in the tutorial are much more intuitive and self-explanatory. So my questions are:

- Is it considered better (or common) to use resourceful routes even in cases like this? or
- Are resourceful routes just a shorthand for cookie-cutter routes, and should only be used for straightforward controllers?

Comment: I'm with you on this one. I'd push back hard on this suggestion. Seems to only add confusion and complication, without any value.

Comment: Thank you, I think so too... if you were pushing this back, would the basis of your argument be that the default routes have better readability (and even if resource routing is more concise, readability matters more)? I'm rather new to the job and would like my reasoning to be as concrete as possible.

Comment: I'd base my argument on the fact that `oauth` is not a resource. Those resourceful actions don't make sense, at all. What does it mean to "list all oauths" (index)? Or what should be the id for show action? Code is written once, but read many times. And this proposed change greatly hurts readabality, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you! Your argument sounds better than just mentioning readability. Shame I can't hit accept on your answer because it's a comment... but thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use the resource(s) helpers. The name tells you it's used for resources and oauth logic are not resources.

You could refactor the routes a little bit though

```
namespace :oauth do
  match :callback, via: [:get, :post]
  get ":provider", action: :oauth, as: :at_provider
end
```

This creates this routes:

```
              oauth_callback GET|POST /oauth/callback(.:format)                                                                oauth#callback
           oauth_at_provider GET      /oauth/:provider(.:format)                                                               oauth#oauth
```

They are basically the same routes, DRYer and without misleading "resource" wording.

*Note the little change from "auth_at_provider" to "**o**auth_at_provider" introduced by the namespace

Comment: This seems like the cleanest way to write these if we wanted to avoid singular routes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is generally considered best practice to use resourceful routing when you're actually doing CRUD on a resource, ie:

```
resources :users # for creating, reading, updating, deleting users
```

If you'd have to create an entirely new resource and controller just for one create endpoint (for example), I don't see any harm in breaking the pattern and using non-resourceful routes, but I try to avoid doing so.

You should try to use resourceful routing with names that makes sense, to keep your routes consistent:

```
scope path: 'oauth' do
  resource :callback, only: [:show, :update] # use show/update instead of callback method
  resources :providers, only: [:show] # use show instead of auth_at_provider
end
```

So your routes would look like:

```
POST oauth/callback
GET  oauth/callback
GET  oauth/providers/:id
```

Comment: Just to clarify - in your alternate solution, are you suggesting that I create two new controller files called `callbacks` and `providers`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Whether you'd rather do that or stick to non-resourceful routes is up to you - most people probably won't have a problem with either. This was is more consistent, however.

Comment: Noted, thanks for the suggestion! I'll bring it up if we ultimately have to resort to resourceful routes for some reason. For now, I'm countering that non-resourceful routes make more sense for this.